# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline: Retrieve Version Number of Key Vault Secret from Variable Group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

In Variable Group I can link to a key vault and retrieve the secret. Is there a way to get the version number of the secret? I can do it differently by creating a task that uses Azure PowerShell and make a call to get a secret object and all of its properties. But if I can leverage this Variable Group feature, it would be much cleaner for my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: you need to get the latest version?

Comment: I need to get the latest version number, not the secret value itself. This is used in a Azure PowerShell function app if you want to retrieve key vault secrets in the function. Yes, it is somewhat backward and based on research, Microsoft has mentioned that this will be fixed in the future (for not having to specify the version number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this is not possible as of today AFAIK, as the latest version of a secret is fetched from the Key Vault and used in the pipeline linked to the variable group during the run. Also, any changes made to already existing secrets in the key vault will also be made available automatically to all the pipelines in which the variable group is used (refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#secrets-management-notes) doc).

However, reading your latest comment above, if this request is being tracked on a public platform with the Azure Team, please feel free to share it here so it benefits others in the community who have similar queries. Thanks for the feedback!